# Visual Studio 2017 export options error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper

Just right after installing Visual Studio 2017, I got ReSharper installed and I made a couple of changes to the settings: Theme, Visual experience, Track active item etc., I think nothing dramatic that might cause an error, but still, I get an error when I try to export the options.

Your settings were exported, but there were some errors.

Error 1:  Failed to export settings for 'Artboard' [code 6708]

Error 2:  Failed to export settings for 'General' [code 6708]

Why would be there an error when saving the general options?

Comment: Who gives you the error message? ReSharper or Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio gave me the error

Answer (score 4):

Closing all VS instances fixed this for me.